# Hide columns upon load of dynamically generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have table that is generated dynamically. I want to hide the columns upon table generation:

My script is as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('load',function() {
        $("#Table1 tr").each(function(){
            $(this).find('td:gt(1)').hide();
        });
    });
```

However, the script above is not working. Please help.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Also, the script as you've pasted it here is missing the `});` which would close your `$(document).ready` call. If that's exactly how your script actually looks, and you didn't just forget to paste that bit into your question, that would be breaking your script!

Comment: Oh, I missed out the }); when copy paste the script. It doesn't work as my Table1 is dynamically generated and hence the columns are not hidden upon table load.

Answer (score 1):

you can't do it like this... you need to do it either in the load callback for the table.. or after the table is loaded you need to trigger a custom event then register a handler for the custom event

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#Table1 tr").each(function(){
        $(this).find('td:gt(1)').hide();
    });
});
```